# Issues installing gems when using Bundler's binstubs

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, rvm, bundler

- Bundler **v1.2.3**
- RubyGems **v1.8.24**
- RVM (latest)
- Rails **v3.2.9**

I'm using binstubs for my Rails application with those defaults (`~/bundle/config`):

```
---
BUNDLE_PATH: .bundle
BUNDLE_BIN: .bundle/bin
```

Then I add `.bundle/bin` to `$PATH` (via a zsh script on chwd, so it's not such a huge security hole) so I have correct gem binaries available.

And this is mostly ok, apart from two issues.

#### Issue 1

When I cd into the app and type `gem list` I get a list of **globally installed gems** (not app's gems). For app gems I need to type `bundle exec gem list` and it works. I can live with that.

#### Issue 2

I cannot have any local (local to the app) gems installed, that live outside of the bundle (i.e. they are not in the Gemfile). One such example is the [gem-ctags](https://github.com/tpope/gem-ctags) gem.

I can theoretically install it into the same directory as all other local gems:

```
gem install --install-dir .bundle/ gem-ctags
```

But I have no way to use it, which is typing this command:

```
☺ gem ctags
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command ctags

☹ bundle exec gem ctags
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (RuntimeError)
    Unknown command ctags
```

Is there a way to make it work?

PS:

- when I install `gem-ctags` into the global gems and then execute `gem ctags` it works as it should)
- I know about [rubygems-bundler](https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler) but I'd rather have just the binstubs working than use it (unless there's no other way...)

### UPDATE

#### Issue 3

`gem cleanup` doesn't work, even though I have $GEM_PATH setup correctly (like @mpapis suggested):

```
☺ gem cleanup                                                                       
Cleaning up installed gems...
Attempting to uninstall rake-10.0.0
Unable to uninstall rake-10.0.0:
    Gem::InstallError: gem "rake" is not installed
Attempting to uninstall ffi-1.1.5
Unable to uninstall ffi-1.1.5:
    Gem::InstallError: gem "ffi" is not installed
Attempting to uninstall dalli-2.2.1
Unable to uninstall dalli-2.2.1:
    Gem::InstallError: gem "dalli" is not installed
Clean Up Complete
```

I can see all of those gems as being installed when I type `gem install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use `.bundle/` you need to put the gem in `Gemfile`

you are trying to use rubygems plugins outside of `GEM_PATH`, to make it working you would have to do:

```
export GEM_PATH="$GEM_PATH:$PWD/.bundle"
```

**UPDATE for Q3:**

According to help:

```
$ gem help cleanup
...
  Description:
    The cleanup command removes old gems from GEM_HOME.  If an older version is
    installed elsewhere in GEM_PATH the cleanup command won't touch it.
```

which means you need for this:

```
export GEM_HOME="$PWD/.bundle"
```

as a side effect it should remove the need for `--install-dir .bundle/`

just so you know - you are doing something unexpected for both bundler and rubygems, and definitively RVM is not ready for your flow.

Comment: Found another issue with that -- Issue 3 (updated the question). Perhaps you'll have an idea on what's causing it?

Comment: Thank you again! This almost works like I have imagined ;) There are some minor issues related to messing with $GEM_HOME in rvm but so far I'm ok with that. Lets see how long it will last ;)

Answer (score 0):

For reference, here's how I **dynamically** add `.bundle/bin` to `$PATH` and `.bundle` to `$GEM_PATH` in zsh to make everything work (i.e. both issues described above are solved):

```
export DEFAULT_GEM_HOME=$GEM_HOME

autoload -U add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook chpwd chpwd_add_binstubs_to_paths

function chpwd_add_binstubs_to_paths {
  # always delete from $OLDPWD (.bundle/bin/ from $PATH and .bundle/ from $GEM_PATH)
  export PATH=${PATH//$OLDPWD\/\.bundle\/bin:}
  export GEM_PATH=${GEM_PATH//$OLDPWD\/\.bundle:}
  export GEM_HOME=$DEFAULT_GEM_HOME

  if [ -r $PWD/Gemfile.lock ] && [ -d $PWD/.bundle/bin ]; then
    # add .bundle/bin to $PATH and .bundle/ to $GEM_PATH (deleting existing entries first)
    export PATH=$PWD/.bundle/bin:${PATH//$PWD\/\.bundle\/bin:}
    export GEM_PATH=$PWD/.bundle:${GEM_PATH//$PWD\/\.bundle:}
    export GEM_HOME=$PWD/.bundle
  fi
}

# initially execute `chpwd_add_binstubs_to_paths` as we might be opening a new shell in Rails project's directory
chpwd_add_binstubs_to_paths
```